# Application of double integrals-finding mass

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

A thin plate occupies region $D$ in the first quadrant above the line $y=x$ and inside the circle of radius $2$ with center $(0,2)$. The mass density of the plate is given by $$\frac{k}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$ for some positive constant $k$. Find the mass of the plate.

I have drawn the region and found out that  $$D= \left\{ (x,y) \mid 0\leq x \leq 2, x\leq y \leq 2+\sqrt{4-x^2}\right\}.$$ Since I chose to use polar coordinates, I determined $0\leq r\leq 2\csc\theta$ however I am having trouble finding $\theta$. Looking at the figure I can directly say that it would be from $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. How can I justify this mathematically?  Also, do the intervals for my $x$ and $y$ seem right? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Using polar coordinates is a good idea indeed.

$r$ varies from $0$ to the circle $r=2\sin{\theta}$, and $\theta$ varies from $y=x$ to $x=0$. If you replace $x$ by $r\cos{\theta}$ and $y$ by $r\sin{\theta}$, you get $r\cos{\theta}=0$ and $r\sin{\theta}=r\cos{\theta}$, and there are only two angles in the first quadrant that satisfy these equations: $\theta=\pi/2$ for the first one, and $\theta=\pi/4$ for the second, as you guessed. So $\theta$ varies from $\pi/4$ to $\pi/2.$

PS: your cartesian intervals are correct too.